# VBA Find Date via Textbox

Tags: excel, vba, select, textbox, find

I have a simple excel list so that I can keep track of the checks I have written in the company.

[Check List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFUd5.png)

[Userform Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccQe1.png)

When entering data to my list; If the check due date I entered in the Textbox on the Userform and the check due date previously written on the last line in my excel list are the same, I can enter the check details at the end of the list with the code below.

If the check due date entered in the Textbox on the Userform and the check due date previously written on the last line in my excel list are not the same; I want to add the due date I entered in the textbox to the list by finding it in the list.

The date I entered the textbox may not be on my list at all. At that time, the date will need to find between which two dates the data should be entered and add a line there.

Unfortunately I haven't been able to do that yet.

I tried below code :

`

```
        Son_Dolu_Satir = Sheets("Çek Programı").Range("C60").End(xlUp).Row
        Bos_Satir = Son_Dolu_Satir + 1

    If TextBox3.Text = Sheets("Çek Programı").Range("C60").End(xlUp).Value Then

        Sheets("Çek Programı").Range("E" & Bos_Satir).Value = TextBox1.Text
        Sheets("Çek Programı").Range("H" & Bos_Satir).Value = ComboBox1.Text
        Sheets("Çek Programı").Range("F" & Bos_Satir).Value = TextBox2.Text
        Sheets("Çek Programı").Range("C" & Bos_Satir).Value = TextBox3.Text
        Sheets("Çek Programı").Range("J" & Bos_Satir).Value = TextBox6.Text

    ElseIf TextBox3.Text <> Sheets("Çek Programı").Range("C60").End(xlUp).Value Then

        Sheets("Çek Programı").Range("C60").End(xlUp).End(xlUp).Row
        Sheets("Çek Programı").Range("E" & Bos_Satir).Value = TextBox1.Text
        Sheets("Çek Programı").Range("H" & Bos_Satir).Value = ComboBox1.Text
        Sheets("Çek Programı").Range("F" & Bos_Satir).Value = TextBox2.Text
        Sheets("Çek Programı").Range("C" & Bos_Satir).Value = TextBox3.Text
        Sheets("Çek Programı").Range("J" & Bos_Satir).Value = TextBox6.Text

    Else

    End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scan up the sheet comparing dates to find the insert position.

```vb
Option Explicit
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Const COL_DATE = "C"

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim Son_Dolu_Satir As Long, r As Long
    Dim dt As Date, dtDue As Date, s As String
    Dim dtFirst As Date, dtLast As Date, num As String
    
    ' check valid date
    s = TextBox3.Text
    If IsDate(s) Then
       dtDue = CDate(s)
    Else
       MsgBox s & " is not a valid date", vbCritical
       Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Çek Programi")
    
    ' check if number is existing
    num = TextBox2.Text
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws.Range("F:F"), num) > 0 Then
       MsgBox num & " is an existing check number", vbCritical
       Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' find row
    With ws
        Son_Dolu_Satir = .Cells(.Rows.Count, COL_DATE).End(xlUp).Row
        
        ' limits of existing data
        dtFirst = WorksheetFunction.Min(.Columns(COL_DATE))
        dtLast = WorksheetFunction.Max(.Columns(COL_DATE))
        'Debug.Print dtFirst, dtLast
          
        ' before first
        If dtDue < dtFirst Then
            .Rows("4").Insert
            r = 4
        ' after last
        ElseIf dtDue > dtLast Then
            r = Son_Dolu_Satir + 2
           
        ' find positon to insert
        Else
            For r = Son_Dolu_Satir To 4 Step -1
                ' skip blanks
                If .Cells(r, COL_DATE) <> "" Then
                   dt = .Cells(r, COL_DATE)
                   If dt = dtDue Then
                        r = r + 1
                        Exit For
                    ElseIf dt < dtDue Then
                        .Rows(r + 1).Insert
                        r = r + 2
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        End If
        
        ' update sheet
        If r >= 4 Then
            .Rows(r).Insert
            .Cells(r, COL_DATE) = dtDue
            .Cells(r, "E") = TextBox1.Text
            .Cells(r, "F") = num
            .Cells(r, "H") = ComboBox1.Text
            .Cells(r, "J") = TextBox6.Text
            MsgBox "Added row " & r, vbInformation
        Else
            MsgBox "Nothing Added", vbExclamation
        End If
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks a lot for your support @CDP1802